# Handlebars helpers as tags

Tags: javascript, regex, ember.js, handlebars.js

Using a regular expression, I'm replacing `**text in bold**` to `<strong>text in bold</strong>` in a string, then displaying `message` using the `{{{message}}}` on my EmberJS templates. Problem is I also want to replace `#anyhashtag` with `{{#link-to "hashtag" "anyhashtag"}}` and it only works with `{{message}}`.

So my idea was creating a `{{strong}}text in bold{{/strong}}` helper which would also be more secure, but apparently helpers only works like `{{strong "text in bold"}}` which won't work if I have links in bold or more complex strings.

Can I do a helper that works like my idea?

Thanks!

Comment: There's a lot going on here. Not sure I see the thing you are really asking about. Can you distill what your use case is, what the problem is, and what you've tried to address it?

Comment: @ahaurw01 so sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit confusing question, but I think this is what you're asking for:

```js
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper("strong", function (options) {
  options.hash.layout = Ember.Handlebars.compile("<strong>{{yield}}</strong>");
  return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view.call(this, Ember.View, options);
});
```

Working [demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jerogiku/1/edit?html,js,output).

---

Actually, a better variant would be this:

```js
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper("strong", function (options) {
  options.hash.tagName = "strong";
  return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view.call(this, Ember.View, options);
});
```

This avoids wrapping `<strong>` into a `<div>`. The first version would be useful if you needed a more complicated wrapper. Updated [demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jerogiku/2/edit?html,js,output).

---

It seems you're trying to create a dynamic template from user-provided content. You can't do that by plugging a template string into a `{{{}}}` construct. 'Triple-mustache' is used for raw html output, it doesn't have a capability of processing additional template code inside it.

Unfortunately, you also can't compile it directly through property. Handlebars compiler is actually producing a function, that then needs to be called with a bunch of Ember-related context stuff in order to generate html.

The best way (that I know of) to get all this sorted out is, once again, through a view. Like this:

```js
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  text: "text in bold",

  html: function() {
    return Ember.Handlebars.compile("{{#strong}}" + this.get('text') + "{{/strong}}");
  }.property("text")
});
```

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <div>Working: {{#strong}}text in bold{{/strong}}</div>
  <div>Working: {{view Ember.View template=html tagName="span"}}</div>
</script>
```

This will display the correct value, but won't update if you change it. To get live update, do this:

```js
App.UpdatableView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateChanged: function () {
    this.rerender();
  }.observes("template")
});
```

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <div>Working: {{#strong}}text in bold{{/strong}}</div>
  <div>Working: {{view App.UpdatableView templateBinding=html tagName="span"}}</div>

  <!-- Type here to see changes -->
  {{input type="text" value=text}}
</script>
```

Updated live demo [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jerogiku/11/edit).

UPDATE: Of course, now that I understand what you're trying to do, I realize you don't really need the first part of the answer, with `{{strong}}` helper.

Comment: Man, you're a genius. But I'm still having a small problem, see: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jerogiku/4/edit

Comment: Updated answer with more info and new jsbin link.

Comment: It works GREAT! I do have a warning though: "WARNING: You're attempting to render a view by passing templateBinding=html to a view helper, but this syntax is ambiguous. You should either surround html in quotes or remove `Binding` from templateBinding."

Comment: Yeah. Either would do. `xxxBinding="something"`, or `xxx=something` and hope Ember will pick up you want to create a binding. I prefer the first one.

Comment: hey @panta82, I discovered that it actually doesn't work in production because Ember.Handlebars.compile is undefined. How can I solve that?

Comment: You're probably using some sort of lean handlebars runtime-only build. You need to make a strategic choice - either allow handlebars compilation on clients and include the full library (suffering a bit longer loading time), or refactor. Maybe you can move this to backend and provide a precompiled template in the asset pipeline. I don't understand what you're trying to do enough to be able to tell what's more feasible / better.